# need help setting up SQLite on eclipse with java for the first time

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I have been trying to figure out how to get SQLite working on eclipse juno.  I have been following the instructions on this site http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite.  The problem is not every step is exactly as explained so I am guessing on weather I got it right or not.  I feel that I have probably gotten it  all correct until step 13, there is no SQL Model-JDBC Connection entry.  So I have tried step 13-16 with a generic JDBC and with one that says SQLite.  The SQLite one does not have a driver which is no surprise due to step 5.  Any way that I have tried so far ends up failing ping with details listed below.  Someone must have a better way through this process.

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SQLite.Database.open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at SQLite.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:68)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you get the driver from *https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads*, then import the driver into your project.

[image]

[image]

Now you can test the configuration by creating a java class `Sample.java`

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;

   public class Sample
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
     {
      // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

      Connection connection = null;
      try
      {
         // create a database connection
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");

         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.


         statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person");
         statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE person (id INTEGER, name STRING)");

         int ids [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
         String names [] = {"Peter","Pallar","William","Paul","James Bond"};

         for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
              statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person values(' "+ids[i]+"', '"+names[i]+"')");   
         }

         //statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE person SET name='Peter' WHERE id='1'");
         //statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM person WHERE id='1'");

           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from person");
           while(resultSet.next())
           {
              // iterate & read the result set
              System.out.println("name = " + resultSet.getString("name"));
              System.out.println("id = " + resultSet.getInt("id"));
           }
          }

     catch(SQLException e){  System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }       
      finally {         
            try {
                  if(connection != null)
                     connection.close();
                  }
            catch(SQLException e) {  // Use SQLException class instead.          
               System.err.println(e); 
             }
      }
  }
 }
```

The code will create a database named `sample.db`, inserting data into, and then prints the rows.

Comment: it did put 2 people in with their id.  So I think it worked as you planned but I am not sure if it is what I am looking for.  Where is this information saved.  it looks a lot like an arraylist.  In my project I put students into an arraylist from a CSV.txt then add or take away points.  I want these points and names to be saved to DB then after a month of running this program I want to export to excel and wipe the DB.  I know an array list will lose the data when I close the program but will this?  If it does then you got it right, and please direct me towards a tutorial to help me with the DB

Comment: I start thinking that you're just asking a lot without trying yourself, I think my answer is what you need (As you asked for the configuration in Eclipse )plus I gave a simple tutorial how you do create, insert , select operation from the DB , and for the db, it's name is **sample.db** (this is portable db) you will find it inside your project folder , just explore it !

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I found the db file.  I don't appreciate the lazy implication. I simply added context to make sure I was heading in the right direction.  I even asked for a tutorial site, so that I may understand and create my own code.  I don't want to just copy yours.  I found it here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm for anyone that would like to follow me. Again, I thank you for being the only person to help me and you did so I +1 and marked as answer. Please keep helping, I would welcome your help again. Just be sensitive to a self taught newb like me.

Comment: +1 , My pleasure to help ! If you encounter any problems just post your questions , I & thousand of ppl ready to help !

Comment: The piece your sample has that Xerial's example doesn't is the part about the class loader (Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")). Once I added this, the sqlite driver loaded. Since I'm new to Java I don't understand yet what this is doing and why the Xerial example doesn't require it. If someone can elaborate, I think it would help make this answer more understandable, but in the interim I will do my own investigation. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Hey @FevlyPallar, I've encountered the problem that eclipse shows me an error at "Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")" and says "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException". What can I do about it?

Comment: @Lunaetic , that means class loader fails to load the driver, make sure you write the code carefully & sqlite-jdbc-x.xx.x.jar is linked correctly to your project files.

Comment: @FevlyPallar thanks, problem disappeared mysteriously when I added the jar again.

Comment: I had a db up and running in three minutes. Less time than it took reading the Eclipse wiki :-). You really deserved an up arrow.